# Excel: return the row number of nearest match to two values

Tags: arrays, indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have two lists with coordinates that I need to match.

One very large list (434,561 rows) structured like this (consider the columns as A,B and C in Excel):

```
code (ID) |  Latitude  |  Longitude
----------|------------|-----------
point455  |  4.513523  |  23.754457
point478  |  74.123523 |  83.757459
[...]
```

Second list (4000 rows) of another set of points with the same structure.

I want to match each points of the second list to the closest coordinated in the first one. Pretty much like this :

```
(second list)
code (ID) |  Latitude  |  Longitude  |  Closest point
----------|------------|-------------|--------------
tag165    |  4.513523  |  23.754457  |  point488
tag198    |  74.123523 |  83.757459  |  point124
[...]
```

I tried matching the latitude and longitude separately. The following formula gives the value in the cell which contains the nearest long value:

`=INDEX(ALLStops!B2:ALLStops!$B$434561, MATCH(MIN(ABS(ALLStops!$B$2:ALLStops!$B$434561-B2)), ABS(ALLStops!B2:ALLStops!$B$434561-B2), 0))`

Both columns have the same formula and are treated independently. I then use `=MATCH(E2,ALLStops!B2:B434561,0)` to get the row.

But about 1/3 of the entries have values where the closest coordinates are on different rows, which is obviously useless.

So the two coordinate values that are matched as closest need to be on the *same row* and i guess the calculation has to be compressed into one.

Can anyone suggest a way of restraining this, or a neater, (and less memory intensive) method?

Comment: I would go with the Pythagorean theorem to determine the difference between two points : let's say you have your `target` and all your `stops`. Subtract `target`'s latitude from each of your `stop` latitude (let's call that variable `dLat`). then do the same for your longitudes (again let's say `dLon`). Then, the square root of the square of those values will be the coordinate differences between those two points : 

`=SQRT(dLon^2 + dLat^2)`

Comment: note though that if you use the coordinates on the surface of a globe, the distance will not be represented at scale : the distance between two longitudes is longest at the equator and smaller and smaller as you go towards the poles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: As per your comment, here is the modified formula.

Assuming that the longer list is available in column A, B & C, and shorter list in F to I, you can use this formula to get the closest match code from the large list against points in the shortlist.

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$434562,SUMPRODUCT((MIN(SQRT(($B$2:$B$434562-G2)^2+($C$2:$C$434562-H2)^2))=SQRT(($B$2:$B$434562-G2)^2+($C$2:$C$434562-H2)^2))*ROW($A$1:$A$434561)))
```

...execute with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Hope this helps

[image]

Comment: Thanks Faseeh, this works but it gives the row number in the short list.  I need the opposite.  I need the row number in the long list that contains the pair of values that are closest to those in the short list.  Because I need the code form the long list.

Comment: I have adjusted the formula, please see if it works.

Comment: This re-arrangement works if you put it inside and IF statement:

{=IF(SHORT!B2="","",SUMPRODUCT((MIN(SQRT((LONG!$B$2:$B$434561-(SHORT!B2))^2+(LONG!$C$2:$C$434561-(SHORT!C2))^2))=SQRT((LONG!$B$2:$B$434561-(SHORT!B2))^2+(LONG!$C$2:$C$434561-(SHORT!C2))^2))*(ROW($B$2:$B$434561))))}

Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: I am getting a couple of weird anomalous values that are outside of the search array.  Any idea why this would happen?   

Row 56 result = 842,240
Row 58 result = 842,208

Comment: I think there are more then one matches and sumproduct is summing row nunbers.

Comment: this was correct.  I cant upvote yet but thanks for your help Faseeh.  Great solution.